# Dynamically added items to nanogallery2 are not shown

Tags: javascript, image-gallery, nanogallery

I am using nanogalley2 to show a galley on a web page. Items of this gallery are fetched from a server and added dynamically to the gallery. I add items based on the [code snipped](https://codepen.io/Kris-B/pen/wJKowg) provided by the official website. But my dynamically added items are not shown (in the cascading layout). I debug the code in the chrome developer tools and I see that items are added to the list of items of the gallery but I had no idea why these items are not shown.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="my_nanogallery2"
    data-nanogallery2='{
        "itemsBaseURL" : "https://example.com",
        "thumbnailWidth" : 310,
        "thumbnailHeight" : "auto",
        "thumbnailDisplayTransition" : "slideUp",
        "thumbnailAlignment" : "center" 
    }'>nanogallery2
    <a href="my-first-image.jpg" data-ngthumb="my-first-image.jpg" data-ngdesc="">My First Image</a>
</div>    
<button type="button" id="btn_add">Load more ...</button>
```

and the JS code:

```
var options = {
    baseUrl : 'https://example.com',
    thumbnailWidth : 310,
    thumbnailHeight : 'auto',
};
jQuery('#btn_add').on('click', function() {
    $http('/api/rest/to/get/some/content')//
    .then(function(res){
        var newItems = res.data.items;
        newItems.forEach(function(item) {
            var instance = $("#my_nanogallery2").nanogallery2('instance');
            // create the new item
            // Parameters: instance, title, description, ID, albumID, kind, tags
            var newItem = NGY2Item.New(instance, item.title, '', item.id, '0', 'image', '');
            // define thumbnail -> image displayed in the gallery
            var itemUrl = options.baseUrl + '/' + item.url;
            newItem.thumbSet(itemUrl, options.thumbnailWidth, options.thumbnailHeight); // w,h
            // define URL of the media to display in lightbox
            newItem.setMediaURL(itemUrl, 'img');
            newItem.addToGOM();
        });
        $("#my_nanogallery2").getElement().nanogallery2('resize');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thumbSet` method requires the real size of each individual thumbnail.

But you're using the size definition of the gallery. And also, the value `auto` can not be used.

One possible solution could be:

```
newItem.thumbSet(itemUrl, item.thumbnailWidth, item.thumbnailHeight);
```